# FileUtils uptodate? issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, file-io, filesystems, rake

I use the uptodate? method in Ruby to determine if a file must be re-compiled/re-linked /re-generated etc. Sometimes the build framework I use is so fast at these steps that the output file and the prerequisite file have the exact same file modification timestamps. This causes the build framework to re-compile/re-link files unnecessarily.

I compare timestamps for building like so -

```
compile_file(file) unless uptodate?(file, %W(#{dependencies}))
```

I looked up the source for uptodate? from [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-uptodate-3F) and it looks like this -

```
def uptodate?(new, old_list, options = nil)
  raise ArgumentError, 'uptodate? does not accept any option' if options
  return false unless File.exist?(new)
  new_time = File.mtime(new)
  old_list.each do |old|
    if File.exist?(old)
      return false unless new_time > File.mtime(old)
    end
  end
  true
end
```

As suspected, it returns false if the timestamps are equal. What's the most elegant way to get around this issue? I have tried running the framework on Linux and Windows and I have the same problem. From what I read [here](https://github.com/joeyates/rake-builder#file-modification-time-resolutions) it's unlikely to be a file system specific file modification time resolution issue (since ext4 has a resolution of 1 microsecond).

Comment: That code is weird, why accept options if you're going to raise an error when people provide them? And I don't understand the problem, if the build framework is so fast, then why does it matter if it occasionally recompiles a file? Unless you're saying that it recompiles the same file many times during the same build. If that's the case, then consider moving to a better tool. [Rake](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial?again), for example, was built for this purpose, and deals with this via dependencies, so it wouldn't have such an issue.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek That code is part of the FileUtils module in Ruby (i.e. it was not written by me!). I am using Rake but I suspect it would behave the same way even if I specified the file dependencies (I am guessing it uses uptodate? internally?).

I don't want the build framework to recompile/re-link/run a unit test unnecessarily, because when you are TDD'ing it does matter!

Comment: Man, there's some weird code in the stdlib O.o Anyway, the difference (If I understand correctly what you're doing) would be that Rake would check that file only one time e.g. it would compile it exactly once, this is because rake tasks are not like methods, but rather like dependencies. File a depends on c, File b depends on c. If you compile both a and b, then c will be compiled once for a, thus the dependency is satisfied for c.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply @JoshuaCheek. I get how file dependencies work in Rake. I abandoned it because my Rakefile became a tangled, unmaintainable mess. 

As far as I understand, Rake file dependencies are re-evaluated internally just like the way I do (I do it explicitly) by comparing file modification timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uptodate?` seems correct.  If the timestamps are equal, the file may be up to date, or it may not.  Therefore it errs on the safe side and declares it out of date.

In the steps where you build files, add logic to advance the time by the built file by a second if it is equal to the time of its dependency.  Yes, it's a hack, but might be the best you can do under the circumstances.

Some file systems (ext4, etc.) can store timestamps with sub-second resolution and might be worth looking at.

Barring any of the above, you can either monkey-patch uptodate? or just create your own that errs on the side of not-building when the timestamps are equal.

Comment: Thanks, your suggested solution should work just fine :) I agree that it is a bit hacky, but it will keep my framework running fast which is very important (because I do TDD).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Ruby's `File` object doesn't support subsecond resolution on file modification timestamps, even if the underlying filesystem does. One solution would be to shell out to `ls --full-time` and parse the result using Ruby's `DateTime`, which does support fractions of seconds:

```
module FileUtilsPlus
  def self.uptodate?(new, old_list, options = nil)
    return true if FileUtils.uptodate?(new, old_list, options)
    return false unless File.exist?(new)
    new_time = filemtime(new)
    old_list.each do |old|
      if File.exist?(old)
        return false unless new_time > filemtime(old)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.filemtime(path)
    DateTime.parse(`ls --full-time foo | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }'`)
  end
end
```

Note that this will be much, much slower than Ruby's native file manipulation, so we'll only do this magic if `FileUtils::uptodate?` returns false.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer, I have accepted the other answer by @WayneConrad because it is a lightweight/speedy solution.